# Avoid returning file path while saving file in response -ParseJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, parse-platform

How to avoid Parse Server from returning file path on calling

```
parseFile.save()
```

Parse JS SDK. Right now it returns-

```
{"url":"https://dsdsdiet-dfdf-18926.dfdfgsddf.com/parse/files/sdasdsadasdaasdasdasd/9bde9df4b8cf6b288ab0abac69b634a1_ok.pdf","name":"9bde9df4b8cf6b288ab0abac69b634a1_ok.pdf"}
```

The API call in background-
* `{"base64":"JVBERi0xLjMKKL1Jvb3QgMTkgMCBSCi9JbmZvIDE4IDAgUgo+PgpzdGFydHhyZWYKMjAyNTIKJSsdsdsdsdsdVFT0Y=","_ContentType":"application/pdf","_ApplicationId":"JxZv88OYGAFtaqdRXnVOYyA107LvsdasdfCbzAK8E7Nkv","_ClientVersion":"js1.6.14","_InstallationId”:”23ds24csdsdsd42b86c493bf5691dd","_SessionToken":"r:d336df5be5d25c75dsdsddfee62d80c44ffdb3ef9"}`

Is there a way I can get only file name instead of absolute path?

Comment: Like`parseFile.save().name`?

Comment: updated question w.r.t. ParseJS SDK, please check

Comment: You want only 'name' in the response(no url)? 
Only your custom parse-server can determine what the data format to return client. Client side without any api to fit what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You may simply split your string on the "/", and keep only the last string in the array returned by the split function.

Here is the doc of the split method : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

It would lead to something like that :

```
var res = myString.split("/");
var file = res[res.length];
```

Does it fill your need ?